# SQL query on distinct row combinations

Tags: sql, relational-database

i have a table, say `Table1` of the following structure:

```
name varchar(20), 
amount integer
```

with an autogenerated ID field. none of the above 2 fields can be null, but can repeat-- aren't necessarily unique.

i'm supposed to query the list of `name`s so that, for each of the names in the list, the following condition must hold:

> the sum of the `amount` of at most `k` number of field(s) for the given name must exceed 1000 where `k`= 3.

so for instance, the name Smith appearing in one row only with amount 1005 is a result in this query. the name Jones appearing 4 times with amounts 200 each won't be returned in this query, but would have been if one of his amounts were 700.

How to do this? one i can think of is inner-joining the table with itself twice, on `name` field, where the condition is the sum of the 3 amounts in the resulting table>=1000 and the row IDs are distinct. 
But, there must be a better way. This logic would fail it `k` would have been a high number, say 100.

Answer (score 1):

I think two joins are called for:

```
select distinct t1.name
from table1 t1 left join
     table1 t2
     on t1.name = t2.name and t1.id < t2.id left join
     table1 t3
     on t2.name = t3.name and t2.id < t3.id
where coalesce(t1.amount, 0) + coalesce(t2.amount, 0) + coalesce(t3.amount, 0) >= 1000;
```

These are `left join`s so you can find combinations with fewer than 3 rows.

The `distinct` is because a single name might have multiple such combinations.

The comparison on the `id` field is to prevent a single row from contributing more than once to a combination.

Comment: @user6762070 . . . "How to do this? "  The question is pretty clear.  If you didn't want an answer like this, you should have included it in your question.

Comment: @user6762070 .. that is rude. you asked a question and it is unfair to post such comments on answers.